# Was Form.create() from antd replaced?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, antd

i am trying to create a login page in react using antd. I found a tutorial for doing this,but i belive that it is outdated, because it gives an error. I read on a forum that form.create() is not available anymore, but i don't know how to replace it.Here is my code:

```
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Spin } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../store/actions/auth';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const antIcon = <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;


class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.props.onAuth(values.userName, values.password);
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let errorMessage = null;
    if (this.props.error) {
        errorMessage = (
            <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>
        );
    }

    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
        <div>
            {errorMessage}
            {
                this.props.loading ?

                <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

                :

                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">

                    <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
                        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
                    })(
                        <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
                    )}
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
                    })(
                        <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    )}
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                    Or 
                    <NavLink 
                        style={{marginRight: '10px'}} 
                        to='/signup/'> signup
                    </NavLink>
                    </FormItem>
                </Form>
            }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.create()(NormalLoginForm);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password)) 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrappedNormalLoginForm);
```

When i try to run it, i get an error that says:

```
TypeError: _antd.Form.create(...) is not a function
```

How can i rewrite the code in order to make it run?

Comment: Are you using v4 or above or antD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AntD has removed `Form.create` in v4 and you can replace the above code with the modified API structure like

```js
class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.props.onAuth(values.userName, values.password);
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let errorMessage = null;
    if (this.props.error) {
        errorMessage = (
            <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>
        );
    }

    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
        <div>
            {errorMessage}
            {
                this.props.loading ?

                <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

                :

                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
                    <FormItem name='userName' rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]}>
                        <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem name="password" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }]}>
                        <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                    Or 
                    <NavLink 
                        style={{marginRight: '10px'}} 
                        to='/signup/'> signup
                    </NavLink>
                    </FormItem>
                </Form>
            }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password)) 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NormalLoginForm);
```

Please see the [`migration guidelines`](https://ant.design/components/form/v3) for more details

Comment: Now it shows me the error:  Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "ConnectAdvanced(NormalLoginForm)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to ConnectAdvanced(NormalLoginForm) in connect options. Do you have any ideea about how coul i solve it? Where should i place the provider?

Comment: Could you please ask a separate question with details about your error and share the link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62288045/where-should-i-place-the-provider-tag-in-antd?noredirect=1#comment110161684_62288045

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `Antd v4.*`. `Form.create({})` is no more in latest version, so you have to your code as follow to make it working. `V4` has. major changes so you have to go through [migration guidelines](https://ant.design/components/form/v3)

```
import { Form, Input, Button, Spin } from 'antd';
import { LoadingOutlined, UserOutlined, LockOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../store/actions/auth';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} />;


class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleFinish = (values) => {
    this.props.onAuth(values.userName, values.password);
    this.props.history.push('/');     
  }

  render() {
    let errorMessage = null;
    if (this.props.error) {
        errorMessage = (
            <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {errorMessage}
            {
                this.props.loading ?

                <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

                :

                <Form onFinish={this.handleFinish} className="login-form">

                    <FormItem name="userName" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }]}>
                    <Input prefix={<UserOutlined style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
                    )}
                    </FormItem name="password" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }]}>

                    <FormItem>
<Input prefix={<LockOutlined style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    )}
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                    Or 
                    <NavLink 
                        style={{marginRight: '10px'}} 
                        to='/signup/'> signup
                    </NavLink>
                    </FormItem>
                </Form>
            }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password)) 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NormalLoginForm);
```